# Angular - NgRx - difference between .select(...) and .pipe(select...)

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using NgRx in my Angular project. I want to access the products that are stored in my store from my `ProductsComponent`.

`ProductsComponent.ts`

```js
...
import { select, Store } from '@ngrx/store';
...
constructor(private store: Store<any>) {}
```

I'm wondering what is the differences between:

```js
public products = this.store.select(selectProducts);
```

and

```js
public products = this.store.pipe(select(selectProducts));
```

and which one I should use.

Answer (score 9):

Both select methods behave the same and have the same functionality.
The difference is that one is a method on the store, while the other is a RxJS pipe.

The NgRx team promotes to use `store.select` because it's more friendly to use (you don't have to import the operator). There's even a eslint rule [select-style](https://github.com/timdeschryver/eslint-plugin-ngrx/blob/main/docs/rules/select-style.md) that encourages to use `store.select`.

Answer (score 0):

The new preferred syntax is

```
public products = this.store.pipe(select(selectProducts));
```

The syntax `this.store.select` is deprecated:

```
  /**
   * @deprecated Selectors with props are deprecated, for more info see {@link https://github.com/ngrx/platform/issues/2980 Github Issue}
   */
  select<K, Props = any>(
    mapFn: (state: T, props: Props) => K,
    props: Props
  ): Observable<K>;
```

See source code here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/store.ts#L27-L33

They've changed that since Rxjs moved to a chained API to a composable one (using pipe and importing the operators you need). This has allowed tree shaking on Rxjs and Ngrx now recommends the new pattern.

Comment: Only the overload that takes props as an argument has been deprecated, the rest of the options are fine.

Comment: Woups, fair enough, good catch. That said, I think it's still a good idea to use the pipeable syntax to stay as close as possible to rxjs API. But timdeschryver seems to say otherwise so I'm confused but you should listen to him :).

Comment: The recommended way nowadays is `store.select(...)`. See the long discussion at https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/1361.

Comment: Indeed, see the actual MR here: https://github.com/ngrx/platform/pull/2711